# C++ Parallel Matrix Multiplication, incorrect calculations

Tags: c++, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp, multiplication

Result of my multiplication is like

```
-842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451   
-842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 
-842150451 -84215045 -842150451 -842150451
-842150451 -84215045 -842150451 -842150451
```

And I don't understand why, can somebody help with this please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS 2

double**        A;
double**        B;
double**        C;
double          t_Start;
double          t_Stop;
int             Am;
int             An;
int             Bm;
int             Bn;

void            Get_Matrix();
void            Mat_Mult_Parallel();


int main()
{
    cout << "Matrix A: ";
    cin >> Am >> An;
    cout << "Matrix B: ";
    cin >> Bm >> Bn;

    Get_Matrix();
    Mat_Mult_Parallel();


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}


void Get_Matrix()
{


    A = new double*[Am];
    B = new double*[Bm];
    C = new double*[Am];
    for (int i = 0; i<Am; i++) { A[i] = new double[An]; }
    for (int i = 0; i<Bm; i++) { B[i] = new double[Bn]; }
    for (int i = 0; i<Am; i++) { C[i] = new double[Bn]; }
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(dynamic)
    for (int i = 0; i<Am; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<An; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 10 +1;
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    printf("\n");

#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(dynamic)
    for (int i = 0; i<Bm; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<Bn; j++)
        {
            B[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            cout << B[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    printf("Matrix Created.\n");
}

void Mat_Mult_Parallel()
{
    int i, j, k;
    t_Start = omp_get_wtime();

    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(dynamic)
    for (i = 0; i<Am; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<Bn; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k<An; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

            }
            cout << C[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    t_Stop = omp_get_wtime() - t_Start;
    cout << "Parallel: " << t_Stop << " seconds." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but the hex of your current output is 0xFFFFFFFFCDCDCDCD. Under visual studio, that 0xCD is uninitialized memory.

Comment: try adding `private(k)` to your `omp parallel for` directive for a starter...

Comment: Ho and BTW, `rand()` isn't thread safe so you will have non-reproducible results at best anyway

Comment: @blazelott Why are you bothering doing this yourself from scratch? Use a library like Armadillo, and link it to OpenBLAS, which will do the multiplication in parallel for you. Reinventing the wheel with linear algebra is nothing but crazy! The BLAS people have been doing this for decades. You can never beat them in performance!

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist Just for educational porpuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not initialize your matrix C, but you use the '+=' operator, adding values to random inital values in matrix C. So you will need something like this first:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < Am; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < Bn; j++ )
    {
        C[ i ][ j ] = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use memset/setmem C function (depending on your system),
which can be quicker.

By the way, do not use 'cout' in parallelized loops, the results might be confusing.

Comment: Small remark: Clever compilers (at least GCC and Intel), will detect such a loop and replace it automatically with `memset`. Fun fact: On some systems, in some configurations, `memset` can be slower than the alternative, presumably because it operates on single bytes only.

Comment: Automatic memset replacement is predicated on a library which uses block stores and switches to cache bypass when needed...